# A word for something judges do before issuing a final verdict?

Tags: word-request

I am not sure what it is, but I vaguely remember that judges tend to do something before issuing a final verdict. They do it to maybe buy some time or something, I don't really know, but I feel like I've heard the word before, but can't remember it at all. It might be a phrasal verb.

For example:

> The judge ___ before issuing the final verdict upon the criminal.
>
> The judge was ___ to issue the final verdict upon the criminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, they ***retire***, meaning leaving the court to sit in *chambers* or a *retiring room* while they work things out.

If there's no jury, and possibly even if there is, they probably ***deliberate***, which in general means carefully thinking about a matter, and in law means to consider the details of a case before coming to a decision.

However, neither of those works in your second example. I'm not sure what that's even getting at.

Comment: Yeah, deliberate seems to be the word.